# Android 4.2.2 RSA disabling

Tags: android

How to disable RSA autentification for android 4.2.2
I has tried following methods:

```
1) setprop ro.adb.secure 0
   getprop still return 1.
2) Root phone and retry method 1 
   getprop still return 1.
3) Root phone and manually change ro.adb.secure to 0 in the /default.prop
   getprop still return 1.
```

Does anybody know how can I disable this check:

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It is a very helpful security feature and can prevent your device from being misused if stolen with debugging enabled.

Comment: @RaghavSood I wan't use this phone with alot of computer, without such problems. Also i have usb switcher between some computers, remoted from my places, i don't want to go there and click on phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's why the methods you tried did not work:

1. ro.* properties are read-only. Once a read-only property is set, it can never be changed or removed. Your ROM is probably setting it in default.prop which is advised very early during init, so setprop will never be able to change it.
2. Same as (1).
3. /default.prop lives on the ramdisk and is only advised early during boot so changing it will have no effect on the property while Android is up and running, and once you reboot default.prop will be back to it's original ramdisk version.

The only way to change this property is to rebuild your boot partition with a modified ramdisk containing a modified default.prop. There's a pretty good HowTo [HERE](http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=HOWTO%3a_Unpack,_Edit,_and_Re-Pack_Boot_Images) on unpacking and re-packing a boot.img on Android.

Comment: Modifying the default.prop file in the boot.img is the way to go.  If you set ro.adb.secure=0, ro.debuggable=1, and persist.sys.usb.config=mtp,adb, you can keep that pesky RSA dialog from showing up.  BTW, I've tried getprop/setprop in the past with root access, but haven't had much luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fixed set of machines you can collect their public keys into a single file and add it to your device.

I described it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15747430/33236) for a single machine but for multiple machines you have to repeat the first step before adding the file in one go to your device.