# Adb over network without previous USB pairing

Tags: android, adb

I have an android 4.2.2 that requires the ADB connection to match an approved fingerprint.

The problem is that the device need to be paired using a USB cable the first time which in my situation will be a problem.

My development environment is running in VirtualBox and I have previously given up trying to get USB to work and instead used the ADB over the network.

The Android SDK Platform-tools is the latest 1601.

Is there any way for me to manually add the key from the virtual machine to my device?

I have a working Android SDK on my host and root access to my device if that can be used to fix this.

Answer (score 22):

This solution requires root on the device.

From the development machine, copy the single line from `$HOME/.android/adbkey.pub`.

```
QAAAAJk..................QA= @myhost
```

And append it to `/data/misc/adb/adb_keys` on your android device. adb_keys contain one key per line so if you previously have paired any other machines they will show up here.

Restart the device.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been looking for something like this to get logs from an initial failing boot :)

Comment: This also helps when adding ADB authorizations to an emulated device. For instance, my compiled CyanogenMod for the emulator (goldfish) did not allow me to add the authorization key otherwise. By the way, I did not need to restart the device, just `adbd`, via `adbd stop` and `adbd start`.

Comment: Finally now I can see the problems in my code when adb is working again